# How to make "Paste from Word" in FCKeditor by default?

Tags: javascript, fckeditor

I need this while copying text from MS word to FCKeditor. The pop up "Paste from Word" should not show up.

Instead I need to internally call the "Paste from Word" function so that the user does not see this pop up.

Basically I need the functionality which is offered by "Paste from Word" but not the popup. And this should be done every time someone  paste text into FCKeditor.

Can we do this?

Help please. This is urgent and I have already spent hours trying to figure out this. :(

### EDIT:

Let me rephrase my question now. I think it will be better I can have `FCKConfig.ForcePasteAsPlainText = true;` as said by Bariz.

But I could not see this anywhere in the fckeditor configuration file.

Any ideas? The version of fckeditor is 2.6.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not know how to set "Paste from Word" by default but maybe You could try pasting as plain text? "Paste from Word" cleans the input but often leaves rubbish in text. You can force pasting as plain text by adding this line to fckconfig.js:

```
FCKConfig.ForcePasteAsPlainText = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is seems to be the nice solution but only thing is that I could not see the above property in the config file.

Comment: The version I am using is 2.6.5.

Comment: Hi. I have set this property, But it is still not working. :(